# anonymous access disabled but

Tags: asp.net, authentication

My web app (asp VB 2005) uses Windows authentication. If the user isn't part of a specific AD security group they don't get to edit the data; instead I redirect the user to a read-only page.

The program works fine in the IDE.

I published the web app to my laptop and Disabled anonymous access. When I ran the program I got redirected to the read-only page. I added a write event to the application event log to see what was going on, and found that the WindowsPrincipal.Identity.Name contained my laptop's ID, not my user name.

I reassert: anonymous access is disabled in IIS and the web.config file has Windows Authentication.

Can anyone suggest what else to check? Or can you explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set `<identity impersonate="true" />` in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <identity impersonate="true" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc.aspx for more details.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest, but you beat me to it ;-)

Comment: Thank you both. I actually discovered this last night so I beat you to it :)  Thanks for the link!

Can someone explain why the "impersonate" setting isn't automatically added to the web.config file?